# Recognize which of the buttons was pressed in the form from the servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my JSP I have one form(action="myServlet", **method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data'**) with 2 submit buttons.

I need to recognize which of those buttons was pressed in myServlet.
If it's possible i would like to avoid using session...

Any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT: -------------------------------------------------------------------------**
All the text below was added after the edit. The **Strong** text is also added with the edit.

Now i have 3 buttons instead of 2, I had to add a javascript function to each one of them(onclick), this function validates the fields before submitting so i had to modify the buttons and set type=button(they are not submit buttons anymore because with submit they would call the servlet always, even if the validation was false).

The method i was using to recognize which of the submit buttons was clicked (in the servlet) was iterating over all the FileItem(s) sent with the request and if the name of any of them was the name of any of the 3 buttons in my form, then that button was the one the user clicked. This worked perfectly when the buttons had type=submit, but now that they are simple buttons apparently they are not sent with the request, so when i get the FileItems in the servlet none of them is any of the buttons... so the trick i was using before is useless now.

I have no idea on how to do this without doing weird things like for example: adding an invisible text field in the form that is filled with the name of the button i click(using javascript)... Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a name to your buttons

```
    <form action="MyServlet.do">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit 1" name="b1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit 2" name="b2">
    </form>
```

then in the Servlet

```
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = (HashMap<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap();
    out.println(map.containsKey("b1"));
    out.println(map.containsKey("b2"));
```

the one that was clicked will be sent and will return true

Comment: To newcomers: this answer was posted before the edit, now the problems I have are different.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i am getting your question correctly. That's what i understand that
now the buttons on your form are not submit buttons anymore. So you want to know which button
was clicked. Okay, i can advice you a solution. You can maintain a hidden input type and when
you click any button, you bind it to a javascript function called as click for example. Here
is the pseudo of the javascript function you should code.

```
function click(){
 // step-1 get a list of all input type using getElementbyId function
 // step-2 check to which ones are buttons
 // step-3 now see whether names are equal to button one or two or three
 // step-4 base on which button was clicked set the value of hidden variable like button1,button2,button3
 // step-5 Retrieve the value of the hidden field in yourservlet and check which one was clicked.
 // step-6 submit the form
}
```

I hope this helps your query.
BR,
Ben

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's exactly what i said I prefered to avoid doing: "I have no idea on how to do this without doing weird things like for example: adding an invisible text field in the form that is filled with the name of the button i click(using javascript)... Any better ideas?".
I didn't want to do it since it seems unnatural and maybe there are good solutions. If there aren't other solutions then i'll implement that invisible input.

Comment: That's fairly a pretty common logic which is followed. You can improve it by adding switch statement may be. Another way can be when you click, send an additional parameter appended to the link. This parameter will tell which button was clicked. But this solution is quiet similar to the previous one. I am also waiting if someone provides a better solution.